# Lucene crawler (it needs to build lucene index)

Tags: java, lucene, web-crawler

I am looking for Apache Lucene web crawler written in java if possible or in any other language. The crawler must use lucene and create a valid lucene index and document files, so this is the reason why nutch is eliminated for example...

Does anybody know does such a web crawler exist and can If answer is yes where I can find it.
Tnx...

Comment: What was your programming-related question?

Comment: AFAIK, lucene doesnot have a web-crawler, chk this out http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're asking is two components:

1. Web crawler
2. Lucene-based automated indexer

First a word of couragement: Been there, done that. I'll tackle both of the components individually from the point of view of making your own since I don't believe that you could use Lucene to do something you've requested without really understanding what's going on underneath.

#### Web crawler

So you have a web site/directory you want to "crawl" through to collect specific resources. Assuming that it's any common web server which lists directory contents, making a web crawler is easy: Just point it to the root of the directory and define rules for collecting the actual files, such as "ends with .txt". Very simple stuff, really.

The actual implementation could be something like so: Use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html) to get the actual web pages/directory listings, parse them in the way you find most efficient such as using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) to select all the links from the fetched document or just parsing it with regex using Java's [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes readily available. If you decide to go the XPath route, consider using [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) for DOM handling and [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) for the actual XPath.

Once you get the actual resources you want such as bunch of text files, you need to identify the type of data to be able to know what to index and what you can safely ignore. For simplicity's sake I'm assuming these are plaintext files with no fields or anything and won't go deeper into that but if you have multiple fields to store, I suggest you make your crawler to produce *1..n* of specialized beans with [accessors and mutators](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm) (*bonus points: Make the bean [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java), don't allow accessors to mutate the internal state of the bean, create a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) for the bean*) to be used in the other component.

In terms of API calls, you should have something like `HttpCrawler#getDocuments(String url)` which returns a `List<YourBean>` to use in conjuction with the actual indexer.

#### Lucene-based automated indexer

Beyond [the obvious stuff](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) with Lucene such as setting up a directory and understanding its threading model (*only one write operation is allowed at any time, multiple reads can exist even when the index is being updated*), you of course want to feed your beans to the index. The five minute tutorial I already linked to basically does exactly that, look into the example `addDoc(..)` method and just replace the String with `YourBean`.

Note that Lucene IndexWriter does have some cleanup methods which are handy to execute in a controlled manner, for example calling [`IndexWriter#commit()`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit()) only after a bunch of documents have been added to index is good for performance and then calling [`IndexWriter#optimize()`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#optimize()) to make sure the index isn't getting hugely bloated over time is a good idea too. Always remember to close the index too to avoid unnecessary [`LockObtainFailedException`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/LockObtainFailedException.html)s to be thrown, as with all IO in Java such operation should of course be done in the `finally` block.

#### Caveats

- You need to remember to expire your Lucene index' contents every now and then too, otherwise you'll never remove anything and it'll get bloated and eventually just dies because of its own internal complexity.
- Because of the threading model you most likely need to create a separate read/write abstraction layer for the index itself to ensure that only one instance can write to the index at any given time.
- Since the source data acquisition is done over HTTP, you need to consider the validation of data and possible error situations such as server not available to avoid any kind of malformed indexing and client hangups.
- You need to know what you want to search from the index to be able to decide what you are going to put into it. Note that indexing by date must be done so that you split the date to say year, month, day, hour, minute, second instead of millisecond value because when doing range queries from Lucene index, the `[0 to 5]` actually gets transformed into `+0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5` which means the range query dies out very quickly because there's a maximum number of query sub parts.

With this information I do believe you could make your own special Lucene indexer in less than a day, three if you want to test it rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at solr search server and [nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) (crawler), both are related to the lucene project.

Comment: Yes they are related but nutch is using modified lucene index's and solr is another type of application. Tnx anyway