# Does solr do web crawling?

Tags: solr, web-crawler

I am interested to do web crawling. I was looking at `solr`.

Does `solr` do web crawling, or what are the steps to do web crawling?

Answer (score 20):

Solr 5+ DOES in fact now do web crawling!
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Older Solr versions do not do web crawling alone, as historically it's a search server that provides full text search capabilities.  It builds on top of Lucene.

If you need to crawl web pages using another Solr project then you have a number of options including:

- Nutch - http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/
- Websphinx - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rcm/websphinx/
- JSpider - http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/
- Heritrix - http://crawler.archive.org/

If you want to make use of the search facilities provided by Lucene or SOLR you'll need to build indexes from the web crawl results.

See this also:

[Lucene crawler (it needs to build lucene index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580882/lucene-crawler-it-needs-to-build-lucene-index)

Comment: Can you elaborate on « Solr 5+ DOES in fact now do web crawling » ? I did not see any crawl feature in the whole documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Solr does not in of itself have a web crawling feature.

[**Nutch**](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/about.html#Overview) is the "de-facto" crawler (and then some) for Solr.

Answer (score 5):

Solr 5 started supporting simple webcrawling ([Java Doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/SimplePostTool.html#webCrawl(int,%20java.io.OutputStream))). If want search, Solr is the tool, if you want to crawl, Nutch/Scrapy is better :)

To get it up and running, you can take a detail look at [here](http://datafireball.com/2016/02/20/solr-simple-post-tool/). However, here is how to get it up and running in one line:

```
java 
-classpath <pathtosolr>/dist/solr-core-5.4.1.jar 
-Dauto=yes 
-Dc=gettingstarted     -> collection: gettingstarted
-Ddata=web             -> web crawling and indexing
-Drecursive=3          -> go 3 levels deep
-Ddelay=0              -> for the impatient use 10+ for production
org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool   -> SimplePostTool
http://datafireball.com/      -> a testing wordpress blog
```

The crawler here is very "naive" where you can find all the code from [this](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/813ca77250db29116812bc949e2a466a70f969a3/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/SimplePostTool.java#L565) Apache Solr's github repo.

Here is how the response looks like:

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting web pages to Solr url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract
Entering auto mode. Indexing pages with content-types corresponding to file endings xml,json,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Never crawl an external web site faster than every 10 seconds, your IP will probably be blocked
Entering recursive mode, depth=3, delay=0s
Entering crawl at level 0 (1 links total, 1 new)
POSTed web resource http://datafireball.com (depth: 0)
Entering crawl at level 1 (52 links total, 51 new)
POSTed web resource http://datafireball.com/2015/06 (depth: 1)
...
Entering crawl at level 2 (266 links total, 215 new)
...
POSTed web resource http://datafireball.com/2015/08/18/a-few-functions-about-python-path (depth: 2)
...
Entering crawl at level 3 (846 links total, 656 new)
POSTed web resource http://datafireball.com/2014/09/06/node-js-web-scraping-using-cheerio (depth: 3)
SimplePostTool: WARNING: The URL http://datafireball.com/2014/09/06/r-lattice-trellis-another-framework-for-data-visualization/?share=twitter returned a HTTP result status of 302
423 web pages indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract...
Time spent: 0:05:55.059
```

In the end, you can see all the data are indexed properly. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at

http://www.crawl-anywhere.com/

Very powerful crawler that is compatible with Solr.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Nutch with Solr on my latest project and it seems to work quite nicely.

If you are using a Windows machine then I would strongly recommend following the '[No cygwin](http://riffelspot.com/nutch/nocygwin)' instructions given by Jason Riffel too!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with the other posts here, use Apache Nutch

> bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5

Although your solr version has the match the correct version of Nutch, because older versions of solr stores the indices in a different format

Its tutorial:
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but in case someone else is searching for a Solr crawler like me, there is a new open-source crawler called [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/collectors/collector-http/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but I'll respond anyway for the newcomer that will wonder here.

In order to use Solr, you can use a web crawler that is capable of storing documents in Solr.

For instance, The [Norconex HTTP Collector](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/http/) is a flexible and powerful open-source web crawler that is compatible with Solr.

To use Solr with the Norconex HTTP Collector you will need the [Norconex HTTP Collector](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/http/) which is used to crawl the website that you want to collect data from, and you will need to install the [Norconex Apache Solr Committer](https://opensource.norconex.com/committers/solr/) to store collected documents into Solr. When the committer is installed, you will need to configure the XML configuration file of the crawler. I would recommend that you follow this [link](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/http/v2/getting-started) to get started test how the crawler works and [here](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/http/v2/configuration) to know how to configure the configuration file. Finally, you will need this [link](https://opensource.norconex.com/committers/solr/v2/configuration) to configure the committer section of the configuration file with Solr.

Note that if your goal is not to crawl web pages, Norconex also has a [Filesystem Collector](https://opensource.norconex.com/collectors/filesystem/) that can be used with the Sorl Committer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Def Nutch !
Nutch also has a basic web front end which will let you query your search results. You might not even need to bother with SOLR depending on your requirements. If you do a Nutch/SOLR combination you should be able to take advantage of the recent work done to integrate SOLR and Nutch ...  http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-442