# Any descriptive tutorials or clear guidance on crawling web by apache solr 6.6

Tags: apache, solr, web-crawler

I read on [this question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781247/does-solr-do-web-crawling) that solr 5+ supports web crawling which means that we no longer need nutch. Are there any examples or descriptions to explain how to set up solr 6.6 crawl a set of remote websites?

Answer (score 1):

they most probably meant [using DIH](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2FHTTP_Datasource) with the right Datasource, but I doubt this can replace Nutch and such in many scenarios.

Comment: Which nutch version is compatible with solr 6.6?